# How to add a phonegap callback for an onTap handler in Sencha Architect 2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I was able to make a complete iphone app from my pc without the mac, runs great on the iphone.

I created the certification and provisioning using openSSL, and the app using sencha Architect trial, then copied the app.html to index.html, uploaded it all to phonegap-build website and voilla I got a working app (and a complex app it is) running on Android and iphone.

BUT, when I want to add the code for the phonegap contacts, I need to add callback code.
I am looking for a fast way to check if my phonegap contacts works AT ALL...
The button onKb1ButtonTapped (my name to the button's tap handler) looks like this:

```
 options = new ContactFindOptions();
 //options.filter="bob"  'nothing will return if you don't have a bob.
 options.multiple=True;
 fields = ["displayName", "name"];
 navigator.contacts.find(fields, onContactsFound, onContactsError, options);
```

Now I need to add the onContactsFound  and the onContactsError code.

**Where/how in Architect2 do I do this?**

**And if we are already talking, How do I get the contacts to be read into my list using a data store and a proxy?**

Of the available store and proxies in Architect the most relevant seemed to be the REST proxy (which Actions need to be overridden calling into new create read update and delete functions) **Is that correct?**

And the memory store seems the best store (but I'm not sure - does that mean that I'll loose the phonegap's returned contacts object, or should I be using a model, and will the array of models returned in the store be lost?

And... Last but not least, when is a Sencha native (packaging) contacts object expected?

Sencha, Thanks for the great work! I love your product.
Same to the Phonegap people!

Moshe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the closing curly bracket in Sencha Architect is inside the event handler.

OK, I now know two ways to do it:

a. answer from here
http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/

I can use an inline function.

Rather than writing:

```
 options = new ContactFindOptions();
 //options.filter="bob"  'nothing will return if you don't have a bob.
 options.multiple=True;
 fields = ["displayName", "name"];
 navigator.contacts.find(fields, onContactsFound, onContactsError, options);
```

I simply use something like this

```
 options = new ContactFindOptions();
 //options.filter="bob"  'nothing will return if you don't have a bob.
 options.multiple=True;
 fields = ["displayName", "name"];
 navigator.contacts.find(fields, 
      function(contacts){
            // do here whatever needed with contacts
      }, 
      function(contactsError){
            // do here whatever you want with error
      , options);
```

=========

Another option is in Architect to go to the controller file (which you probably created by adding an event-binding to a button, and then converted it to an action) and there OVERRIDE the CODE. Then in the override code, after the main method adding whatever you want.